# Vaadin 7 and Spring injection - does not work correctly

Tags: spring, vaadin, vaadin7

I integrated Vaadin and Spring, but @Inject only works in the main UI.
This is my main class.

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@PreserveOnRefresh
@Slf4j
public class AdminPanelMain extends UI {

    @Inject //It works
    private UserService userService;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

//  @Inject
    private Panel tagsPanel = new TagsPanel();
```

UserService
Service - it's just a test version yet, it's nothing, I'm just trying to get it as a bean.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class UserService {

//  @Autowired
//  private UserRepository userRepository;

    public void saveUser() {

//      log.info("count: {}", userRepository.count());
        log.warn("saved");
    }
}
```

TagsPanel
The TagsPanel is one of many components, and each I would like to be able to have the Spring-service.

```
public class TagsPanel extends Panel implements Property.ValueChangeListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired //null
    private UserService userService;


    public TagsPanel() {

        initLayout();

    }
.......
}
```

ApplicationInitializer

```
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        rootContext.register(ApplicationConfiguration.class);
        registerSpringContextLoaderListener(servletContext, rootContext);
        registerVaadinServlet(servletContext, rootContext);
    }

    private void registerVaadinServlet(ServletContext servletContext, AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext) {

        VaadinServlet vaadinServlet = new VaadinServlet();
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic vaadinServletRegistration = servletContext.addServlet("vaadinServlet",
                vaadinServlet);
        vaadinServletRegistration.setInitParameter("ui", AdminPanelMain.class.getName());
        vaadinServletRegistration.setInitParameter("UIProvider", SpringUIProvider.class.getName());
        vaadinServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        vaadinServletRegistration.addMapping("/*");

    }

    private void registerSpringContextLoaderListener(ServletContext servletContext,
            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext) {
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextCleanupListener());
        servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
    }
}
```

**When I create a class TagsPanel, then UserService already null. Why?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of solving the integration of spring and vaadin yourself you could also use the newly proposed *official* spring/vaadin integration.

This integration can be found at github on https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring.
And most interesting is that this integration is implemented by two core developers of Vaadin and Pivotal (spring). And it is quite easy to set up by just adding some annotations (as described on github project website).

In future it will also integrate spring security and spring i18n support to vaadin.

Comment: I've seen and their presentation and this implementation. Tell me if it's better than? What are the challenges I will face if I continue in this direction now?

Comment: As I see the examples are with spring boot. It is nice, but in some cases(including mine) spring boot is not used and i found that the question is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Because you created it with `new`. Spring container can only configure managed beans (ie, beans created by the container) . It will work if you autowire it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved. When I did INJECT. I throw out a mistake that a lot of the panels with the same name.

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@PreserveOnRefresh
@Slf4j
public class AdminPanelMain extends UI {

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private Panel addUserPanel;

    @Inject
    private Panel tagsPanel;

.....
```

That's what I was getting an error.

```
13:25:51,286 SEVERE [com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler] (default task-3) : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminPanelMain': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; ne
sted exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.vaadin.ui.Panel com.jdev.blog.admin.AdminPanelMain.addUserPanel; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factor
y.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.vaadin.ui.Panel] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: TagsPanel,UserPanel
```

The solution

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@PreserveOnRefresh
@Slf4j
public class AdminPanelMain extends UI {

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private UserPanel addUserPanel;

    @Inject
    private TagsPanel tagsPanel;

.....
```